# teaching about sessions?

Tags: c#, asp.net, html

Can any one teach me how to use sessions? I have a login page which refers to mysql db table named User which includes UserID="variable number", username and password. Id like to be able to store the userid in a session so I can call it inside the users profile when he logs in.

How is this done? Any relevant coding and placement of specific coding would be helpful as Im just not picking it up at all. Does it go inside the code behind (.cs file) or is it held in the html of the aspx page? or both and how? How does the session work across multiple inner pages (once logged in you can broswe more than one page related to your own profile)

```
    using System.Data.Odbc; 
    partial class login : System.Web.UI.Page 
    {        
    protected void   Login1_Authenticate(object sender, System.Web.UI.WebControls.AuthenticateEventArgs e)     
    {         
    OdbcConnection cn = new OdbcConnection("Driver={MySQL ODBC 3.51 Driver};Server=localhost;Database=mydb; User=root;Password=;");         
cn.Open();
         OdbcCommand cmd = new OdbcCommand("Select * from login where username=? and password=?", cn);          
    //Add parameters to get the username and password            
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@username", OdbcType.VarChar);   
      cmd.Parameters["@username"].Value = this.Login1.UserName;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@password", OdbcType.VarChar);  
       cmd.Parameters["@password"].Value = this.Login1.Password;  

        OdbcDataReader dr = default(OdbcDataReader);        
 // Initialise a reader to read the rows from the login table.   

  // If row exists, the login is successful        
    dr = cmd.ExecuteReader();        
  if (dr.HasRows) 
{             
e.Authenticated = true;             
// Event Authenticate is true       
    }    
  } 
}
```

Comment: Bear in mind that the session collection is volatile so your UserID value may be removed midsession. You should always provide a fallback to repopulate values in the event that they are removed.

Comment: how? what other options would you suggest if sessions are that volatile?

Comment: if (Session["UserID"] == null)...then look up the ID again

Comment: As DOK mentioned, check if the userID is null and retrieve it if it is. You should be able to use User. You could store the identifier within User.Identity.Name which will remain constant throughout a validated session.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In C#, to store a variable in a Session variable:

```
Session["usrID"]="myUserName";
```

Later, to retrieve the Session variable:

```
string usrName = Convert.ToString(Session["usrID"]);
```

Comment: omg it cant be as simple as that? But altho the user logs in all he is inputting is his username and password the userid part of mysql table isnt refrenced? I will edit my post and include the login code (its a asp login control changed to run from mysql)

Comment: Don't you get the UserID back from the SELECT * FROM login?

Answer (score 3):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx

Basically, give yourself a property for each variable in the page class, eg.

```
private int SelectedYear
{
    get 
    { 
        object obj = Session["SelectedYear"];
        if (obj != null)
        {
            return int.Parse(obj.ToString()); 
        }
        else
        {
            return 0;
        }
    }
    set { Session["SelectedYear"] = value; }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

if you need something for user management, you should go with a membershipprovider. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f1kyba5e.aspx

to get userinformation you can use

```
Membership.GetUser()
```

if you just want to use sessions to store variables, you can easily use

```
Session["name"] = value;
var value = Session["name"];
```

like others already mentionend

Answer (score 1):

When should you call the code to set the Session variable value?

You can do that in the `Login_Authenticate` method. That it where you have first retrieved the ID.

Or, you can do it in the `Global.asax` file, in the `Session_Start` event. Then, you will always have the value available on every page.